# Compressing Wordpress content with Cloudfront

Tags: wordpress, nginx, amazon-cloudfront, nginx-config

I've spent quite a bit of time reading through Cloudfront documentation and updating configurations.

I have Cloudfront pointing to my nginx instance which proxies my Wordpress site. All static assets are getting compressed as expected. However, non static assets such as the index or blog pages are not getting compressed at all.

My presumption was that since the `content-length` header is not being sent back from the origin in those requests for non-static content (and is for the static content) that Cloudfront would reject compressing those responses as per the documentation.

I'm wondering if my understanding is correct, and if there is any way I can configure this set up to have Cloudfront gzip/brotli compress these pages.

I tried disabling chunking on nginx, enabling and disabling compression on nginx, as well as trying to downgrade from http/2 to http/1.1 or lower in hopes to prevent nginx from chunking the content when Cloudfront requests it.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudfront will not compress again if your origin returns response with header  Content-Encodin. You can tell cloudfront to compress objects by mentioning that in cache behaviour , have a read of this document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html